# In Xcode, under Info tab, what's Role for in URL Types section?

Tags: ios, url-scheme, info.plist

In Xcode, under Info tab, what's Role dropdown in URL Types section for? The valid value for this is Editor, Viewer, None.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It represents what your app can do with the URL / file type.

- Editor == read and write.
- Viewer == read only.
- None == can't use at all.

This flag isn't used by iOS.

Comment: What file type are you referring to?

Comment: Do you have any documentation on that? Is this used for Mac apps?

Comment: @ciryx, yes, it is used on Mac OS X. Check the docs for info.plist keys on the Apple dev site.

Comment: It is for MacOS actually. The actual key is `CFBundleTypeRole` and [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html)

Comment: I don't think the archived doc you mentioned is helpful. `CFBundleTypeRole` appears twice, and in the URL section, it says "iOS" and "macOS".