# Custom URL Scheme Parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-foundation, url-scheme

When defining the custom URL scheme for my app there are 3 keys that I need information  about:

1. `CFBundleTypeRole` a.k.a Document Role
2. `CFBundleURLName` a.k.a URL identifier
3. `CFBundleURLSchemes` a.k.a. URL Schemes

I can see, if I just define `CFBundleURLSchemes` to be `myapp` the app is launching fine with an URL as `myapp://`. 
Questions are:

1. Is the URL identifier there only to make my scheme unique? How does
   it do that? If I have same  scheme `myapp` defined in 2 apps, and I call `myapp://`
   can I specify which one I want to call by calling `myapp://<URL Identifier>`? 
   **Edit:** What does this URL Identifier actually do? Does it only give a name to url? How it is used?
2. The Role defines the level of permission which is
   `None, Viewer or Editor,` I am not sure what level of permission my
   app has on the launched app as I have not defined anything. I would
   like to know what is the default permission when the
   `CFBundleTypeRole` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## to 1:

A protocol is not guaranteed to be unique. There is no parameter you can define that will open app1 or app2. If two apps use the same scheme it is undefined what happens

## to 2:

the role is irrelevant for the most part BUT **mandatory**:

- editor = launched because  they can R/W files identified by the same
- viewer = can only read and display

Comment: roles are more important when it comes to document types IMHO

Comment: But when I don't define anything in the Role, what is the default role?

Comment: docs: "This key is required." -- read as: no default because needed.

Comment: As I stated, I am able to launch my app without specifying the key. Though it states to be required.

Comment: yes, sure you are and then you have an undefined state

Comment: Thanks @Daij-Djan for your response. The question boils down to: whether my application is safe when the key is not defined.

Comment: I would guess it is safe for now but as soon as you can: change it

Comment: I did understand the key is "REQUIRED", but my current app which was in the App Store did not have this key defined. That is the reason I wanted to know whether it is safe or not. Honestly, saying "REQUIRED" does not really tell me whether it is safe, does it? Thanks for your advice, I am planning to change it in the next release. Just assessing my current situation. Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Ad 1)

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1) they don't give much info about the identifier and why it is needed or where it is used. They only say that it should be unique.

Also if more than one app specify the same url scheme, then the outcome is unpredictable.

See [URL identifier and URL scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597631/url-identifier-and-url-scheme)

### Ad 2)

The Role flag isn't used by iOS.

See [In Xcode, under Info tab, what's Role for in URL Types section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598352/in-xcode-under-info-tab-whats-role-for-in-url-types-section)